# How to transfer param from js file to javascript in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I have some variables in sort-item.js file and want to trasfer them to js in html.

Here are the details:
Because of Django CSRF protection when post data, I could only put the $ajax function in html like this:

```
<html>
<body>...</body>
<script>
    var post_data = {
        "name": "saveorder",
        "item_id": item_dataid,
        "from": from_index,
        "to": to_index,
        "order": order
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: post_data,
        ...
    });
</script>
<html>
```

Meanwhile I have got this below in sort-item.js and can show the data in console log:

```
var itemContainers = Array.prototype.slice.call(kanban.querySelectorAll('.board'));
itemContainers.forEach(function (container) {
.on('dragReleaseEnd', function (item) {
    ...
    var item_dataid = item.getElement().getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(item_dataid);
    var order = muuri.getItems().map(item => item.getElement().getAttribute('data-id'));
    console.log(order);
})
.on('move', function (data) {
    var from_index = data.fromIndex;
    var to_index = data.toIndex;
    console.log(from_index + ' ' + to_index);
})
}
```

My question is how to transfer data.fromIndex, data.toIndex, order from sort-item.js to javascript variable post_data in html?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by use a globle variable in sort-item.js.